# How to install specific azure cli version in dockerfile - ubuntu image

Tags: dockerfile, ubuntu-18.04, azure-cli

I'm using ubuntu:18:04 image
I want to install azure cli specific version.
This is the command

```
# Use specific version of Azure cli
RUN apt-get update \ 
    && sudo apt-get install -y --allow-downgrades azure-cli=2.49.0-1~focal
```

I got this version from running **apt list -a azure-cli**
[image]

Error that I receive is

```
#7 8.554 E: Unable to locate package azure-cli
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update     
&& sudo apt-get install -y azure-cli=2.40.0-1~focal --allow-downgrades]: exit code: 100
```

I would love to install it with apt-get not with pip or something else. If you have any idea what might be please respond. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems first step needs to be to download azure-cli with latest version.

```
# Azure cli
RUN curl -LsS https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

I saw in logs that this is the latest version -> **2.51.0-1~bionic**
So I just put **2.{myversion}.0-1~bionic**

## Use specific version of Azure cli

```
RUN apt-get update \ 
    && sudo apt-get install -y --allow-downgrades azure-cli=2.49.0-1~bionic
```

You will get these logs which means it works [image]